# Meeting creation addin for outlook with C#

Tags: outlook, vsto

I need to create an outlook addin that will do the things I listed below before sending a meeting request:

- Check how many users are in the To list, warn if there are more than predefined number of users
- Warn if subject line is empty
- Warn if word "attachment" is used in mail body but no attachments can be found in the mail

Is it possible to do this with Office Interop or with a VSTO addin? I need to intercept and cancel the sending of meeting request if one of the rules above doesn't meet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with VSTO. I did use it in the past to make an outlook addin to add a dynamic signature to a message before send it. You can subscribe to events to check your rules, and allow or cancel your meeting request.